# Include foreign characters in groovy split collect

Tags: groovy, split, collect

I'm having an issue with converting foreign names to upper/lower case...
It seems to omit foreign characters.
Any idea how I could solve this?

```
String str = "SÉBASTIEN DOL DE BRETAGNE";
return str.split(/[^\w]/).collect { it.toLowerCase().capitalize() }.join(" ");

Current output: S Bastien Dol De Bretagne
Desired output: Sébastien Dol De Bretagne
```

I would like to have it work with all foreign characters (Swedish, French etc) but I'm at a lost :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're splitting on non-word characters, and that's the problem. `\w` is `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` (See the [`Pattern` class's JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)), which does not include `É`. That explains why this character, in either case, is being used as a delimiter.

You could split by spaces or blanks:

```
//any version of these, specifying the delimiter
s.split(/ +/).collect { it.toLowerCase().capitalize() }.join(" ")
s.split(/\s+/).collect { it.toLowerCase().capitalize() }.join(" ")
```

Both of the above return `"Sébastien Dol De Bretagne"`

Answer (score 2):

Another option: use `replaceAll` to replace all non-whitespace
characters.  E.g.

```
String str = "SÉBASTIEN DOL DE BRETAGNE";
println str.replaceAll(/\S+/, { it.toLowerCase().capitalize() })
// → Sébastien Dol De Bretagne
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by using the Apache Commons [Lang3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3) library:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils

String str = "SÉBASTIEN DOL DE BRETAGNE"

assert WordUtils.capitalizeFully(StringUtils.lowerCase(str, Locale.ENGLISH)) == 'Sébastien Dol De Bretagne'
```

You can look up different Locales [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html?is-external=true#field_summary)